# Moment of Inertia of a uniform sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, geometry, moment-of-inertia

I'd like to calculate the moment of inertia of a uniform sphere using the universal formula for calculating moments of inertia, I=$\int{r^2\mathrm dm}$. Here, r should be the distance from the axis of rotation rather than the distance from the center of the sphere. If we have the sphere rotate about its z-axis, then r is actually rcos$\theta$ in spherical coordinates, so I=$\int{r^2\cos^2\theta \mathrm dm}=\int{r^2\cos^2\theta\rho \mathrm dV}$. The density of a uniform sphere is $\rho=\frac{3m}{4\pi R^3}$ so

$$I=\frac{3m}{4\pi R^3}\int_0^{2\pi}{\int_0^\pi{\int_0^R{r^4\cos^2\theta \sin\theta \mathrm dr\mathrm d\theta \mathrm d\phi}}}$$
$$I=\frac{3m}{4\pi R^3}\left(\frac{1}{5}R^5\right)\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)(2\pi)=\frac{1}{5}mR^2$$
This is a factor of 2 off from the actual answer, which is $\frac{2}{5}mR^2$. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? I understand that there are other ways of doing this problem involving disks or cylinders, but I'd like to understand what's wrong with what I'm doing here since it seems to be the most mathematically straightforward method.

Comment: Check better your integrals.

Comment: Your integral has two problems.  Since the angle (θ) is measured from the xy plane, the limits should be  (- π/2) to (+ π/2).  Also, since the angle (ϕ) is measured in the xy plane, the incremental arc should be [r cos(θ) dϕ] not sin(θ).  You may need to look up the integral of $cos^3$(θ) dθ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integrating term should $r^2\sin^2(\theta)$
not $r^2\cos^2(\theta)$

Comment: Why is that? If you imagine the sphere spinning about the z axis, the distance of a point from the z axis should be $rcos\theta$ by basic trigonometry.

Comment: Oh wait, nevermind. I completely forgot where $\theta$ is measured from. Thanks!